# Is there any way to store Shopify pages in git?

Tags: git, shopify

I'm using the `theme` tool for Shopify themes, and it works really well. I can edit my themes locally and store them in git.

Is there anything similar for the "pages"? Right now I still have to go into their web app to edit them, which is a huge pain, and I can't use version control.

Answer (score 0):

Pages are [accessible via the API](https://help.shopify.com/api/reference/page) so it wouldn't be a big deal to extend the [theme tool](https://github.com/wilr/grunt-shopify) to read and write pages from a local file system. Once there you can use git all you like.

Answer (score 0):

Api the only one way to update admin panels content like pages, products, collections etc.

But it's much difficult to update using api.

Better way is manage manually version control for your updates.